# Gerar MER de uma Database

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, modelagem

Tenho o backup de uma Database e por falta de documentação estou precisando gerar o MER dele.
Eu lembro de ter lido em algum lugar, que existem programas que fazem essa engenharia reversa e gera o MER.

Poderiam me ajudar com isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso o próprio SQL SERVER MAnagemnet Studio gera.

1) Abre o SQL SERVER Management Studio

2) Conecta com o banco de dados desejado.

3) No Object Explorer expanda na árvore a pasta Databases -> Nome do seu banco de dados -> Database diagrams.

4) Se não tiver nenhum, clica com o botão direito em Database Diagrams, e New Database Diagram...

5) Ai só escolher as tabelas que vc quer que apareçam no diagrama e partir pro abraço.

Comment: Amigo ele só gera pra mim o modelo lógico, seria possível gerar o modelo conceitual?

Comment: Ai acho que só ferramenta de terceiro. Até onde sei não tem no Management Studio.

Comment: @Lucas: o "Database diagrams" gera o diagrama com a implementação física. Não há como se obter MER confiável a partir do banco de dados. Chaves substitutas, por exemplo, podem ser implementadas pelo DBA e obviamente não existem no MER. Afora outras otimizações que podem ser implementadas na etapa de _fisicalização_.

Comment: Vlw pela explicação @JoséDiz . Eu usei o Power Designer pra gerar o MER da DB